# How to force import module in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have two packages with structure like this:

```
Package1/calc1.py
Package1/utils.py

Package2/calc2.py
Package2/utils.py
```

calc1.py looks like this:

```python
#calc1.py
import utils
...
```

and calc2.py looks the same:

```python
#calc2.py
import utils
...
```

Also, I have the main module with main.py file. It starts like this:

```python
import package1.calc1
import package2.calc2
```

After running main.py, I got the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'utils'
```

It happens because when calc1.py import utils (from Package1), utils added to cache. So when it is time to import utils from Package2 by calc2.py, utils already in the cache and I got the error. These utils files a different and I can't rename them, they should have the same names, it is important.

The question is like that: are there any possible ways to force import modules to rewrite cache, or maybe clear module cache?

Comment: You should do `import package1.utils` or `import package2.utils` as appropriate.

Comment: This has nothing to do with caches.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thank you for your advice. Here is a toy example. The packages are too complex and has a lot of imports so it is hard to rename imports. And also it is unrecommended to change packages code.

Comment: @cyberspace have you tried relative imports? e.g. in both `calc1.py` and `calc2.py` do `from . import utils`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy No, because calc1.py and calc2.py could be called as standalone scripts (not like a modules).

Comment: Also, I can't reproduce the error locally - instead I get `ModuleNotFoundError: no module named utils` when trying to import either package. I would recommend just importing one of them, doing `sys.modules.pop('utils')`, and then importing the other, and see if that fixes it (essentially, removing `utils` from the cache), but I can't test that

Comment: *utils already in the cache and I got the error*.  That's not the case, please don't assume the source of your error without due info.  This has everything to do with your project structure and nothing to do with cache.  I'd suggest you remove that assumption from your question.

Comment: @r.ook It is literally because of cache. When Python imports module and loads it to the memory, he "remember" it and when you will try to import module with the same name, he will check it in his cache (modules list) and raise an error.

Comment: If you insist it's a caching issue, you can remove the `.pyc` files in `__pycache__` folders and rerun your module.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this has nothing to do with caching and has to do with your project structure.  You should be using absolute path import or relative path import in your `calc1.py` and `calc2.py` modules.  [Here is an example:](https://repl.it/repls/SpatialStrikingAbstraction)

**Project Structure**:

```
/
├ main.py
├ pkg1
│  ├ calc1.py
│  └ utils.py
└ pkg2
   ├ calc2.py
   └ utils.py
```

**main.py**:

```
import pkg1.calc1
import pkg2.calc2

pkg1.calc1.times5()
pkg2.calc2.times10()
```

**calc1.py**:

```
# absolute path import
from pkg1 import utils

def times5():
  print(utils.name)
  print(f'{utils.val} x 5 = {utils.val * 5}')
```

**pkg1.utils.py**:

```
name = 'using pkg1.utils.py'
val = 1
```

**calc2.py**:

```
# relative path import
from . import utils

def times10():
  print(utils.name)
  print(f'{utils.val} x 10 = {utils.val * 10}')
```

**pkg2.utils.py**:

```
name = 'using pkg2.utils.py'
val = 2
```

**Output from main.py**:

```
using pkg1.utils.py
1 x 5 = 5
using pkg2.utils.py
2 x 10 = 20
```

You can also read more on [absolute vs relative imports here](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my packages have deep tree structure with a lot of imports, so refactor it replacing relative imports to absolute imports it too complicated. I have solved this problem using docker on every package to isolate it.

Comment: While it's complicated it is still the proper way to fix your project structure than to isolate your packages.  Imagine you needing to export this module outside of your environment, it'd be needlessly difficult compared to a proper structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is `reload()` function in `imp`/`importlib` module

For Python2.x

```
reload(module)
```

For above 2.x and <=Python3.3

```
import imp
imp.reload(module)
```

For >=Python3.4

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(module)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't do it because I can't make import, I mean application crashed before reload.